# He iniciado un proyecto laravel 8 con Inertia,vue3 y vuex4; y al momento de usar this.$store me sale indefinido

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, vuex, inertia.js

He creado un proyecto con laravel8, inertia, vue3 y vuex 4, y el problema que tengo es el no poder usar la tienda ya que al momento de llamar al `this.$store.state.count` me bota que el `state` es indefinido. No entiendo por qué no me funciona con laravel8. Tengo lo siguiente en la carpeta de *resources/js/app.js*:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

// Import modules...
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import { store } from './Store';
const el = document.getElementById('app');

createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
        }),
})
    .mixin({ methods: { route } })
    .use(InertiaPlugin,store)
    .mount(el);

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });

console.log(store.state.count)
```

y en el archivo de *resource/js/Store/index.js* tengo lo siguiente:

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export const store = createStore({
    state () {
        return {
            count:0
        }
    },
    mutations:{
        INCREMENT(state){
            state.count++
        },
        DECREMENT(state){
            state.count--
        }
    }
})
```

y al momento de probar su funcionalidad de vuex4 en el archivo *resources/js/Pages/Dashboard.vue*:

```js
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Dashboard
            </h2>
        </template>

        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                    Contador es : {{ count }}
                    <button @click="increment">+</button>
                    <button @click="decrement">-</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout'
    import Welcome from '@/Jetstream/Welcome'
    import { useStore } from "vuex"
    import { ref, inject } from "vue"

    export default {
        components: {
            AppLayout,
            Welcome,
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log("montado correctamente");
            console.log(this.$store);
        },
        setup(){
            // const store = inject('store');
            const store = useStore();
            console.log(store);
            const count = ref(0);
            const increment = () => {
                count.value++;
            };
            const decrement = () => {
                count.value--;
            };
            return { count, increment, decrement };
        }
    }
</script>
```

obtengo lo siguiente: que en ambos `console.log(this.$store)` y `console.log(store)` son indefinidos y además que la inyección `store` no se encuentra.

Answer (score 0):

lo único que me funcionó fue separar el use en el app.js.

Quedaría así:

```
const app = createApp({
  render: () =>
    h(InertiaApp, {
      initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
      resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
    }),
}).mixin({methods: {route}})
  .use(InertiaPlugin);

app.use(store);
app.mount(el);
```